Cookie not sent back to server: problem with DNS / CORS
I'm building a web page with Angular in front-end (being served via GitHub Pages), and Google Cloud Functions / Node.js in back-end.
For example, there is a route /api/user/create where a make a POST request with Angular HttpClient, setting { withCredentials: true }. If I visit https://striderhobbit.github.io/psycho-cli directly, everything is working fine.
But if on GitHub Pages I set a custom domain (https://www.tecstures.com), it is not. I can log in, receiving a response cookie
connect.sid 
expires "2024-04-09T09:06:23.000Z"
path    "/"
samesite    "None"
secure  true
value   "s:p6moM7Q_zD50xUsCl2ns8kA608tE1qb4.zkz7Y91fcqs+YTfVdtKV4yAqnTofhPogvhdWMo0g2yQ"

but /api/user/create most of the time fails, because no cookie is being sent back / session is missing (I checked in dev tools: request cookie is empty). In rare cases it's working, without any code changes. So I can only suspect it has to do something with server response time.
But note: It must have something to do with setting the custom domain in GitHub, because without it's working all the time.
Server is looking like (express + express-session):
const app = express();

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: ["https://tecstures.com", "https://striderhobbit.github.io"],
    credentials: true,
  })
);
app.set("trust proxy", true);
app.use(express.json());
app.use(
  session({
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 300000,
      httpOnly: false,
      secure: true,
      sameSite: "none",
      partitioned: true,
    },
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    secret: generate(10),
  })
);

On GitHub everything is looking fine:

On squarespace (where my custom domain is hosted) I have

UPDATE
To reproduce go to https://tecstures.com/#/events, and then follow these steps:

You should get an error
Error: Missing authentication at EventService.authorize (/workspace/lib/src/services/base.js:13:19)...


I could resolve this problem by implementing openapi-generator-cli. Also, in iOS you have to enable Disable Cross-Origin Restrictions in Safari settings.
This is the setup that's working:
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: [
      ...
    ],
    credentials: true,
  })
);
app.set("trust proxy", true);
app.use(
  session({
    cookie: {
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: true,
      sameSite: "none",
      partitioned: true,
    },
    ...
  })
);

